# constant vector in c++ class

Tags: c++, class, vector, constants

```
class myClass {
    const std::vector<int> myVec = {1,1}; //works
    //const std::vector<int> myVec (2,1); //doesn't work
}
```

I'm trying to define a constant vector in a class.

Why the first line works while the second line doesn't?

The error is

```
g++ test.C
test.C:6:35: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
     const std::vector<int> myVec (2,1);
                                   ^
test.C:6:35: error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
```

Comment: Non-static data members can be initialized with [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) or with a [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).

Answer (score 1):

```
const std::vector<int> myVec (2,1);
```

starts to define a function named `myVec` returning a `const std::vector<int>` but then instead of naming the types of the arguments you have integer literals.

Did you mean

```
const std::vector<int> myVec {2,1};
```

or

```
const std::vector<int> myVec = std::vector<int>(2, 1);
```

Comment: Note that "`(` starts to define a function" only applies at class scope.

Comment: Dear Goswin,
thank you so much for your prompt reply
I meant the latter, to declare and assign a variable in one go
The syntax of `const std::vector<int> myVec (2,1);` works well standing alone, but not working inside a class